# AS3: Event Listener Not Firing

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am brand new to AS3/Flash and am learning about event handling.  I have a "Bell" class which dispatches an event, and if I add an event listener to an instance of that Bell class, it works fine.  That's not what I want, though.  I've got another class, Pet, which I would like to have listening for the Bell.  I see the trace from the bell, but not the one for the pet.

**Here is the code for the Bell:**

```
public class Bell extends EventDispatcher {
    public static const BELL_RING:String = "bellRing";
    public static const RING_INTERVAL:int = 1500;
    private var ringIntervalID:int;

    public function Bell()
    {
        ringIntervalID = setInterval(ringBell,RING_INTERVAL);
    }

    public function ringBell():void {
        trace("RINGING THE BELL");
        dispatchEvent(new Event(Bell.BELL_RING));
    }
}
```

**...and for the Pet:**

```
public class VirtualPet {
    private var senseOfHearing:EventDispatcher = new EventDispatcher();

    public function Pet(name:String):void
    {
        senseOfHearing.addEventListener(Bell.BELL_RING,heardBell);
    }

    public function heardBell(e:Event):void {
        trace("Pet hears bell ringing");
    }
}
```

**...and for the Main Class:**

```
public class VirtualZoo extends Sprite
{
    public function VirtualZoo()
    {
        var bell:Bell = new Bell();
        var pet:VirtualPet = new VirtualPet('Stan');
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!  Events are properly imported and there are no compiler errors.

Comment: How are the two Classes connected?

Comment: Sorry, I updated it, adding the main class to the end.

Comment: If you want the bell to respond to the pet, you'll have to pass a reference to the bell object, to the pet, so that the pet can then register a listener for it and respond when needed.

Comment: The event listener needs to be added to the class instance that dispatches the event. In your case, `Bell` dispatches event but the event listener is added to an instance of `EventDispatcher`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, this is the most straight-forward...

```
public function Pet(name:String, bell:Bell):void {
    bell.addEventListener(Bell.BELL_RING, heardBell)
}
```

Then:

```
myBell = new Bell()
myPet = new Pet("dog", myBell)
```

Or...

if Bell is a child of Pet, then you can bubble the event up the DisplayList and capture it in Pet (but I doubt this is the case).

Or...

You can use a proxy class, like your `senseOfHearing` and pass that instance to both Bell and Dog and use it to dispatch events between the two.

**EDIT**
Based on your comment:

```
var bells:Array = [];
// add some bells
var pet:Pet = new Pet("Marvin", bells);

public function Pet(name:String, bells:Array):void {
    for (var i:int = 0; i < bells.length; i++) {
        bells[i].addEventListener(Bell.BELL_RING, heardBell);
    }
}
```

Comment: So in other words, an event listener for a bell must be attached to a bell...any old class can't just wait for the signal sent from bell, it's got to be a bell listening for itself.  Is that correct?

Comment: No, it is the `Pet` listening for the `Bell`.  The `Pet` instance has a reference to something that will dispatch an event.  When one of these events is fired, you want to listen for it in `Pet`.  So, in `Pet` you add an EventListener for a specific event `Bell.BELL_RING` which is dispatched by the `bell` instance.

Comment: Think of it like `somethingThatDispatchesEvents.addAnEventListenerHereForThisEvent(SomeEvent, someLocalHandler)`

Comment: Alright, I get it.  Is there a way for an object to access the main class's instance variables?  So, could I have an array in VirtualZoo with all the bells, and iterate through the array from my Pet class without the array being static?

Comment: To clarify, you have lots of bells, and you want your `Pet` to listen for each one?

Comment: Alright, I was hoping the language included a better option for accessing an insantiating class's instance variables, but we get what we get I suppose.  Thank you so much for all your help sberry, I really appreciate it.  Have a good one!